# /cmdVel topic: cmdVel(roll, pitch, yawrate, thrust) for crazyflie

Tags: ros2, quadcopter, uav, drone

We are working on Crazyflie 2.1 to implement our controller by utilizing ROS2. We used the following repository on GitHub to make it possible.

[crazyflie experimental](https://github.com/knmcguire/crazyflie_ros2_experimental.git)

We'd like to access `/cmdVel` topic to send the related control inputs (i.e., roll, pitch, yawrate, thrust) to Crazyflie. However, when we start Crazyflie, we could not see the `/cmdVel` topic (we assumed this is a default topic for Crazyflie). I added the topic list below. How could we fix it, let us now if you have any useful explanation for this situation, thanks.

```
ntukenmez3@ae-icps-407120:~/Documents/2023-crazy-flie-1/crazyflie_ros2_experimental/crazyflie_ros2_implementation$ ros2 topic list 
/cmd_vel
/odom
/parameter_events
/rosout
/scan
/tf
/zrange
```

Comment: Just to make it easier for people to follow your support question: 1- Post which package source you are using so it is readable for other people that are not the maintainer. 2- Add labels to your question like UAV or such. 3- And make it more generic such that people that don't know the crazyflie can still help out. You can add those improvements now already to your answer.

Comment: I'll edit my question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm the creator of this package [crazyflie_ros2_experimental](https://github.com/knmcguire/crazyflie_ros2_experimental) so I'll try to help out. It is an experimental github ROS package that is no longer maintained (), but I'll try to help out if you want to get it to work.

So the topic is called [/cmd_vel](https://github.com/knmcguire/crazyflie_ros2_experimental/blob/f2b78f9a085e7421c0dfea02c383644819514410/crazyflie_ros2/crazyflie_ros2/crazyflie_publisher.py#L40) . cmd_vel is a more commonly used topics for velocity reference commands in the form of twist commands. Here you can see the [callback for that](https://github.com/knmcguire/crazyflie_ros2_experimental/blob/f2b78f9a085e7421c0dfea02c383644819514410/crazyflie_ros2/crazyflie_ros2/crazyflie_publisher.py#L180). This controls the crazyflie's velocity in x,y,z and control its heading by yaw. That is more or less the 'standard' use of cmd_vel with twist within the ROS community.

*Just some background history about why /cmdVel has been used for attitude commands in some packages*. So the notion that /cmdVel means: roll/pitch/yaw to the crazyflie, has its origins at the original [Crazyflie ROS package](http://wiki.ros.org/crazyflie) (see [the callback here](https://github.com/whoenig/crazyflie_ros/blob/master/crazyflie_driver/src/crazyflie_server.cpp#L310)). This eventually made its way to the [Crazyswarm project](https://crazyswarm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but for [crazyswarm2](https://imrclab.github.io/crazyswarm2/) this will be deprecated as it is not the norm anymore within ROS anymore.

So you want to send roll,pitch,yaw commands to the Crazyflie instead that will be difficult as that does not exist in this package. So you will need to make your own subscription, call it something else ('/ctr_att') or something else. Reuse the Twist message or use a different one. And make your own callback function that uses this [crazyflie python api function](https://www.bitcraze.io/documentation/repository/crazyflie-lib-python/master/user-guides/python_api/#sending-control-setpoints-with-the-commander-framework):

```
crazyflie.commander.send_setpoint(roll, pitch, yawrate, thrust)
```

Again a disclaimer, the crazyflie-ros2-experimental package is not maintained and if you'd like to use this functionality, look at the Crazyswarm2 project which is more actively maintained and supported and ask for help there.

Comment: Well, thank you for your helpful and precious comments.

Comment: Firstly, my question was about generic `/cmd_vel`  as in `self.cmdVelPublisher = rospy.Publisher(prefix + "/cmd_vel", geometry_msgs.msg.Twist, queue_size=1)`. You can check the related topic from this website ([crazyswarm github](https://github.com/USC-ACTLab/crazyswarm/blob/master/ros_ws/src/crazyswarm/scripts/pycrazyswarm/crazyflie.py)). I had hoped that it could be available in your repository as a default topic.

Comment: Secondly, as much as I understood from there, this default topic (`/cmd_vel`) lets us to send roll, pitch, yaw rate and thrust inputs to Crazyflie. However, I could not get the following comment, if possible for you, could you explain it a little bit more, thanks.  "_This eventually made its way to the Crazyswarm project but for crazyswarm2 this will be deprecated as it is not the norm anymore within ROS anymore._"

Comment: Lastly, as you mentioned, I am supposed to write my subscriber() to send the related inputs to Crazyflie such that `crazyflie.commander.send_setpoint(roll, pitch, yawrate, thrust)` can be run with a user-defined topic name.

Comment: About cmdVel in crazyflie_ros/crazyswarm2, I was just explaining a bit of history of why this package used /cmdVel for pitchrollyaw even though that isn't the standard in the ROS community (which is cmd_vel for velocity commands) to give some context. This comment of mine is not really for support but more for context of the question :)

Comment: about /cmd_vel being a default topic in the crazyflie-ros2-experimental repository, it is already implemented but it is currently only responding to velocity commands. This temporary project was unrelated to crazyswarm2 and fully separated, and there for the project I rather wanted to do it more the 'standard' ROS way. Unfortunately I do not have ambition too implement a special topic for rollpitchyaw since this project is over already and I no longer will maintain it.

Comment: That said, you are completely free to fork the repository and change it to your own liking, like indeed, changing the cmd_vel callback function to send attitude setpoints instead of velocity setpoints to the crazyflie. That is all within your own power :)

Comment: Update: I used `self._cf.commander.send_setpoint(roll, pitch, yawrate, thrust)` in my subscriber. It looks it is working.

Comment: I have another question at this point, that is shared on GitHub btw :) How could we access `stateEstimate.vx`, `stateEstimate.vy`  and `stateEstimate.vz`  (Crazyflie linear velocities). I used default functions to add those variables. Could you also help us to fix it, thanks. I`ll ask my question on this website with a different question definition.